# JavaScript Promise - how to make multiple promise?

Tags: javascript, express, promise, es6-promise

How can I chain the multiple promise? For instance:

```
var promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {

    // Compose the pull url.
    var pullUrl = 'xxx';

    // Use request library.
    request(pullUrl, function (error, response, body) {
        if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
            // Resolve the result.
            resolve(true);
        } else {
            reject(Error(false));
        }
    });

});

promise.then(function(result) {

    // Stop here if it is false.
    if (result !== false) {
        // Compose the pull url.
        var pullUrl = 'xxx';

        // Use request library.
        request(pullUrl, function (error, response, body) {
            if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
                resolve(body); // <-- I want to pass the result to the next promise.
            } else {
                reject(Error(false));
            }
        });
    }

}, function(err) {
    // handle error
});

promise.then(function(result) {

    // Stop here if it is false.
    if (result !== false) {
        // handle success.
        console.log(result);
    }
}, function(err) {
    // handle error.
});
```

Error:

> resolve(body);
>       ReferenceError: resolve is not defined

Any ideas?

Comment: @ray he's within a callback at that point... so no that's a bad idea.

Comment: if `request` doesn't return a promise, you need to promisify it and then make sure you return the result from `request(...)` from the `.then`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When chaining Promises, then return value from a function given to then should either be a Promise, or the value to pass along.

In your case, since you're making an async call, you'll just return another promise and call `reject` or `resolve` within there. If it wasn't async, you could just return the value, or throw an error, which also gets passed along to the next then or error handler/catch as appropriate.

Also, you need to chain them together, because each then() returns a different Promise.

So, something like this:

```
var promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {

    // Compose the pull url.
    var pullUrl = 'xxx';

    // Use request library.
    request(pullUrl, function (error, response, body) {
        if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
            // Resolve the result.
            resolve(true);
        } else {
            reject(Error(false));
        }
    });

});

promise.then(function(result) {

    // Stop here if it is false.
    if (result !== false) {
        var airportCode = result;

        // Compose the pull url.
        var pullUrl = 'xxx';

        // Use request library.
        return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
            request(pullUrl, function (error, response, body) {
                if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
                    resolve(body);
                } else {
                    reject(Error(false));
                }
            });
        });
    }

}).then(function(result) {
    // Stop here if it is false.
    if (result !== false) {
        // handle success.
        console.log(result);
    }
}).catch(function (err) {
  // handle error
});
```

Here is a JSFiddle with a working version: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bLvbjcho/)

Comment: thanks for the answer but i get `undefined` for `console.log(result);`....

Comment: @teelou Are you using my first answer where I said to return it, or are you using my updating answer which wraps it in a Promise? My first version didn't realize you were using async.

Comment: yes that was the first answer that i tried. but still the same after trying the edited answer.

Comment: @teelou Hmm, it should be working. I added a JSFiddle to mine that shows "Cake" as the response. If you update your question to include your latest code, I might be able to spot something.

Comment: Aww I see I have to use multiple `new Promise`!

Comment: @teelou Yeah, with async calls, you have to create another promise and return that promise. There isn't any way around that. If it wasn't async, you could have just returned the value.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! :-)